# Failure to run protractor from Node.js command prompt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, protractor

Hope all is well. I'm setting up protractor for the first time through Node.js. This is provided as part of a tutorial on the AngularJS website under "Running E2E Tests":
https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

However, while executing protractor through the provided command "npm run protractor", I get the following error within the Node.js command prompt:

```
E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "protractor"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-phonecat@0.0.0 protractor: `protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 199
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-phonecat@0.0.0 protractor script 'protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-phonecat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-phonecat
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-phonecat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Here is the contents on the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "angular-phonecat",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "A tutorial application for AngularJS",
  "repository": "https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.7.7",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^0.1.7",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "protractor": "^4.0.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install",
    "prestart": "npm install",
    "start": "http-server ./app -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1",
    "pretest": "npm install",
    "test": "karma start karma.conf.js",
    "test-single-run": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "preupdate-webdriver": "npm install",
    "update-webdriver": "webdriver-manager update",
    "preprotractor": "npm run update-webdriver",
    "protractor": "protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js",
    "update-index-async": "node -e \"var fs=require('fs'),indexFile='app/index-async.html',loaderFile='app/bower_components/angular-loader/angular-loader.min.js',loaderText=fs.readFileSync(loaderFile,'utf-8').split(/sourceMappingURL=angular-loader.min.js.map/).join('sourceMappingURL=bower_components/angular-loader/angular-loader.min.js.map'),indexText=fs.readFileSync(indexFile,'utf-8').split(/\\/\\/@@NG_LOADER_START@@[\\s\\S]*\\/\\/@@NG_LOADER_END@@/).join('//@@NG_LOADER_START@@\\n'+loaderText+'    //@@NG_LOADER_END@@');fs.writeFileSync(indexFile,indexText);\""
  }
}
```

I don't know if anyone else has tried this same tutorial and is getting the same issue? Any help would be most appreciated, thank you.

Comment: did you start the selenium server?

Comment: you need to run the command `npm run protractor` from the folder where your package.json is located.also can you post the content of `package.json ` file

Comment: I'm not sure if I started the selenium server Danny, could you advise how I can check? Sure Sudharsen, I've added the contents of the package.json file to the question.

Answer (score 1):

So Protractor can be started in several ways, the most common are by `directConnect` or by `seleniumAddress`. Since no value was set in the `e2e-tests/protractor.config.js` file, the assumed value is `directConnect`. To get `directConnect` to work with the chrome browser, you'll need to get the latest chromedriver. To just install chromedriver:

```
./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update --standalone=false --gecko=false
```

Or as suggested in the [github angular-seed page](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed#end-to-end-testing) which will download, in addition, the selenium standalone jar file and gecko driver (which is used for firefox):

```
npm update-webdriver
```